# Private JavaScript functions - this.name vs. var name

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions

If I'm using some private functions in a class do certain naming conventions yield better performance or offer different functionality...or is it simply a matter of preference?

```
var MyClass = function() {

   var private1 = function(msg){
       // Do stuff.
       console.log(msg);
   };

   this.private2 = function(msg) {
       // Do stuff.
       console.log(msg);
   };

};
```

Comment: `this.private2` is not as private as its name implies.

Comment: @Tibos yes sir. I was just trying to access the method directly on the class like a dummy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two variables have very different access so which one to use depends upon which type of access you want to offer, not just a coding style preference.

In your example, `private1` is a local variable to your constructor and is ONLY available to code inside the constructor.  It is NOT available to any code outside the constructor.  It is actually private.

```
var yourObj = new MyClass();
yourObj.private1();   // undefined, will not work
```

`private2` is an instance variable of a `MyClass` object you create with the `new` operator and is reachable by any code as `yourObj.private2()`.  It is not private in any way - it is a publicly reachable method.  Example:

```
var yourObj = new MyClass();
yourObj.private2();     // works
```

So `private1` is private and `private2` is public.  One should select the implementation method that matches the desired goal of the code.  This is not just a coding style preference.

Comment: That's what I was thinking re: MyClass.priavte2(), but when I was trying to test it I kept getting this error http://d.pr/i/UptR hence why I was calling private2 "private" because I wasn't able to successfully use it outside the closure.

Comment: @Swordfish0321 you have to create an instance first: `var myclass = new MyClass(); myclass.private2();`

Comment: @Swordfish0321 - code examples for `private1` and `private2` added to my answer.

Comment: Dammit, don't know how I missed that. Thanks and good answer!

Answer (score 1):

private1 is a function inside constructor MyClass and private2 is function of MyClass instance:

```
var cl = new MyClass();
console.log(cl.private1); // undefined
console.log(cl.private2); // function
```